# How to add a shadow and a border on circular imageView android?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I created a CircularImageView with this question: [Create circular image view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208365/1832221)

Download project on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)

1) This is the CircularImageView class :

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return; 
        }
        Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);      

        Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, getWidth());
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);      
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));

        Canvas c = new Canvas(output);        
        c.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        c.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        c.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

2) I use in my layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCircular"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/image_view_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/image_view_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3) Current result in picture :

[image: Current result]

**How do I change this code to have a shadow and a circular border around my imageView?**

Objectif result :

[image: Objectif result]

---

**Edit 10/15/2015 :**

You can used or download my **GitHub library** [**CircularImageView**](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) with **all the fixes** by using **gradle dependency** :

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'
```

Comment: I dont know what kind of app you're making, but it looks awesome

Comment: @lopez.mikhael Your code works and it's really good! But its possible to use wrap_content in width and height? It's crashing when I've tried.

Comment: @DanielNazareth You're right, it's impossible to use wrap_content in width and height currently. I have not had time to change it. The trouble comes from that I made ​​using the dimensions of the image to draw the circle. Using wrap_content I lose this information. Of the problem will be fixed, I will warn you.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael could you fix memory lake on this library? i think this problem is for android 6

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I modified the [CircularImageView found here](https://github.com/wisemandesigns/CircularImageView) to achieve what you want.

To create a shadow around the border, I simply used these two lines:

```
this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
```

You need `setLayerType` due to hardware acceleration on HoneyComb and up. It didn't work without it when I tried it.

Here is the full code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircularImageView extends ImageView
{
    private int borderWidth = 4;
    private int viewWidth;
    private int viewHeight;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;
    private BitmapShader shader;

    public CircularImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup();
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        // init paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        setBorderColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth)
    {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor)
    {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);

        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void loadBitmap()
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) this.getDrawable();

        if (bitmapDrawable != null)
            image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // load the bitmap
        loadBitmap();

        // init shader
        if (image != null)
        {
            shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);
            int circleCenter = viewWidth / 2;

            // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
            // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
            // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

        viewWidth = width - (borderWidth * 2);
        viewHeight = height - (borderWidth * 2);

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text
            result = viewWidth;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight, int measureSpecWidth)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = viewHeight;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

.

**EDIT**

I forked your CircularImageView and added support for selector overlays. I also improved drawing performance significantly...

https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: Is there a way to add the shadow to a RoundedImageView https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView ?

Comment: Great solution - works a dream. It doesn't seem to keep the aspect ratio of a rectangular image though.

Comment: Can you please help me out in giving shadow to different shapes like polygon, stars, etc. ?

Comment: The shadow's api is confusing to me. It is either true or false, but how do you set the width, position, etc? (setting to true does not draw any shadow for me)

Comment: what if i dont want the corners of my image to get cropped because of this circular background

Comment: @Pkmmte sir it is use to free or not

Comment: it works only for image. If i set color for background then my app crashes

Comment: can it have a border and a padding between the border and the image?

Comment: setLayerType method causes onDraw to be called recursively. Anyone has an idea to how to solve this? Or is it just the normal behavior, which will definitely drain battery?

Answer (score 15):

To add a border by making `ImageView` as a circle, i've done a simple thing, I used this class to  make my image as a circle

```
package com.fidenz.fexceller.fexceller;

/**
 * Created by Chathu Hettiarachchi on 5/18/2015.
 */
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class RoundedImg extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundedImg(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

and by using this on `onCreate` i have call the image for setting it,

```
profilePic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_home_profile_pic);

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_image);
roundedImage = new RoundedImg(bm);
profilePic.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
```

to add a border i created a circle shape XML like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/ring_color" android:endColor="@color/ring_color"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

then using layouts i added a `RelativeLayout` with `ImageView` inside of it, by using padding and background drawable with `wrap_content` i set my `RelativeLayout` like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lay_rel_img"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/img_home_profile_pic"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

now it show like this, i don't know to add the shadow, sorry for that too

[image]

Comment: dat padding in the relative layout was the eyeopener

Answer (score 3):

1. Add 
   `canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getWidth() / 2, paint);` 
   before 
   `canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);`
2. Change 
   `c.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2, sbmp.getHeight() / 2, sbmp.getWidth() / 2, paint);` 
   to 
   `c.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2, sbmp.getHeight() / 2, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 - "the border with you prefer", paint);`

Hope it helps.

Maybe a better solution [here](https://github.com/wisemandesigns/CircularImageView).

Comment: Great, border work. It lacks the shadow effect, you would have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom drawable, and use that to define your the background attribute of your ImageView.  You can use a LayeredDrawable, to create as many different components for the component as you would like.

Checkout this answer, which creates a custom Rectangle (but is exactly the same with an Oval\Circle):  [How to create Google + cards UI in a list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571118/how-to-create-google-cards-ui-in-a-list-view/17571277#17571277)

Answer (score 2):

I found a library that doing exactly what you wish, worked fine for me.
Check it out.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/932

Answer (score 1):

just use drawCircle() method  with more width and height before drawing the actual image. Increase the width and height of in that new method call according to your wish, and set some another color of you want on paint

Comment: I made a first circle with the color of my border. Then I created a second smaller circle that will contain my image, it works. However, my second, smaller circle is not centered on my first. How can I do this?

Comment: write the center and radius of these both circles, their center points should be same

Comment: for shadow you can use paint.setShadowLayer(float radius, float dx, float dy, int color)

Answer (score 0):

This Class is Custom Circular Imageview with shadow, Stroke,saturation and using this Custom Circular ImageView you can make your image in Circular Shape with Radius. Guys for Circular Shadow ImageView No need Github this class is enough.

Adding CircularImageView to your layout

// Bitmap myimage=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.pic);
    CircularImageView c=new CircularImageView(this,screen width,screen height,Bitmap myimage);
    yourLayout.addView(c);**

```
public class CircularImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView  
{
    private final Context context;
    private final int width, height;
    private final Paint paint;
    private final Paint paintBorder,imagePaint;
    private final Bitmap bitmap2;
    private final Paint paint3;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private BitmapShader shader;
    private float radius = 4.0f;
    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 8.0f;
    private float stroke;
    private float strokeWidth = 0.0f;
    private Bitmap bitmap3;
    private int corner_radius=50;


    public CircularImageView(Context context, int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap)     {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

   //here "bitmap" is the square shape(width* width) scaled bitmap ..

        this.bitmap = bitmap;


        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);


        paint3=new Paint();
        paint3.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint3.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint3.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        imagePaint= new Paint();

        paintBorder.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);


        this.bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (bitmap.getWidth() - 40), (bitmap.getHeight() - 40), true);


        imagePaint.setAntiAlias(true);




        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Shader b;
         if (bitmap3 != null)
            b = new BitmapShader(bitmap3, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
         else
            b = new BitmapShader(bitmap2, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        imagePaint.setShader(b);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskedBitmap(), 20, 20, null);
    }

    private Bitmap maskedBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap l1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(l1);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(radius, x, y, Color.parseColor("#454645"));
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        final RectF rect = new RectF();
        rect.set(20, 20, bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight());

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, paintBorder);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, imagePaint);

        if (strokeWidth!=0.0f)
        {
            paint3.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, corner_radius, corner_radius, paint3);
        }

         paint.setXfermode(null);
        return l1;
    }




     // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 250"  here corner radius will change 

    public void setCornerRadius(int corner_radius)
    {
        this.corner_radius = corner_radius;
        invalidate();
    }



    -------->use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 10.0f"  here shadow radius will change 

    public void setShadow(float radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
        invalidate();
    }

   // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 10.0f"  here stroke size  will change 

    public void setStroke(float stroke)
    {
        this.strokeWidth = stroke;
        invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap updateSat(Bitmap src, float settingSat)
    {

        int w = src.getWidth();
        int h = src.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmapResult =
                Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvasResult = new Canvas(bitmapResult);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        colorMatrix.setSaturation(settingSat);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
        paint.setColorFilter(filter);
        canvasResult.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);

        return bitmapResult;
    }




  // use seekbar here, here you have to pass  "0 -- 2.0f"  here saturation  will change 

    public void setSaturation(float sat)
    {
        System.out.println("qqqqqqqqqq            "+sat);
        bitmap3=updateSat(bitmap2, sat);

        invalidate();
    } 


}






        // Seekbar to change radius

                  radius_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            text_radius.setText(""+progress);
                            circularImageView.setCornerRadius(progress);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


     // Seekbar to change shadow

                    shadow_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            float f= 4+progress/10.0f;
                            text_shadow.setText(""+progress);
                            circularImageView.setShadow(f);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


           // Seekbar to change saturation

                    saturation_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            int progressSat = saturation_seekbar.getProgress();
                            float sat = (float) ((progressSat*4 / 100.0f)-1.0f);
                            circularImageView.setSaturation(sat);

                            text_saturation.setText(""+progressSat);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });


    // Seekbar to change stroke

                    stroke_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            if (progress==0)
                            {
                                float f=(progress*10.0f/100.0f);
                                circularImageView.setStroke(f);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                float f=(progress*10.0f/100.0f);
                                circularImageView.setStroke(f);
                            }

                            text_stroke.setText(""+progress);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        }
                    });




             //radius seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="50"
                android:max="250"
                android:id="@+id/radius_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





          //saturation seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="50"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/saturation_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />





    //shadow seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/shadow_seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




         //stroke seekbar in xml file

             <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:progress="0"
                android:max="100"
                android:id="@+id/stroke _seekbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```