# Making an image circular with white circular border

Tags: android, layout, imageview, geometry, drawing

How to make an image circular and give it white circular border? Is it necessary to use two image views – one for the image and other for the white border? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I already have code for making image circular and its working fine.Now i need to put a white circular border for that.Can i do that with same code or do something else ?This is my question.

Answer (score 23):

Try this...

```
public static Bitmap getCircularBitmapWithWhiteBorder(Bitmap bitmap,
        int borderWidth) {
    if (bitmap == null || bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        return null;
    }

    final int width = bitmap.getWidth() + borderWidth;
    final int height = bitmap.getHeight() + borderWidth;

    Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    float radius = width > height ? ((float) height) / 2f : ((float) width) / 2f;
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, paint);
    paint.setShader(null);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderWidth / 2, paint);
    return canvasBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First add below line to **build.gradle** file

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

then add following **XML** code to **xml** file:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

First get Circulat image with your code.
Then apply this xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#333440" android:endColor="#333440"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Then add a relative layout and add an imageview to it.Arrange it to the center of relative layout.And set this circle shape as Imageview's background.Then place your circular imageview above previously added imageview.Arrange it also to center.By changing your circular imageview margin you will get the desired border effect.
Hope this will help you..

Comment: I already have code for making image circular and its working fine.Now i need to put a white circular border for that.Can i do that with same code or do something else ?This is my question

Comment: Check updated answer.. and have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19393571/2591002)

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the best way and you may not be able to change a lot of properties, but it is surely the easiest way. I just used [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) library and I made a circular imageview that has also a border.

---

So, this is my solution:

**First**, I put this in my `build.grandle`:

```
`compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'`
```

**Second**, I put this in my `.xml` layout file:

```
 <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:id="@+id/photo"
                    app:siBorderWidth="5dp"
                    app:siBorderColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

In my `.java` file, this is the way I can take or set the image to the `CircularImageView`:

```
final com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView photo = (com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

photo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female);
```

---

That's all I've done to do the an image circular with white border.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not necessary that you have to use two image views one for the image and other for the white border. You can create one new XML file like below

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

and then set it to your image-view. Like add below line to your image-view.

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

Comment: But "@drawable/border" means that i should provide an image inside drawables named border na ?

Comment: No just create one new xml file in your drawable folder if drawable folder does not exist then you can also put inside your drawable-mdpi folder then just copy and paste the content above listed in border.xml, no need to put image inside, then set this line `android:background="@drawable/border"` to your image-view.

Comment: @maria, are you getting what i am trying to say.

Comment: Can you post your updated code for both border.xml and image-view.

Comment: I am not able to post code here.Something is wrong :(

Comment: Please find my code here for image view here http://codeshare.io/2Cg9J and the code for border.xml here http://codeshare.io/7wQZD

Comment: But your border.xml does not contain the code which i gave you, please put that code and try.

Comment: See my updated code paste this code inside your border.xml again, then clean your project and run it again.

Comment: This is how i got the image after doing what u said http://postimg.org/image/svv95w47j/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209101951/http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2012/09/crop-image-in-circular-shape-in-android.html) for it.

in this tutorial they use a Method:-

/*
  * Making image in circular shape
  */

```
public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int targetWidth = 50;
  int targetHeight = 50;
  Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, 
                            targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
  Path path = new Path();
  path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
  ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
  (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), 
                ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
          Path.Direction.CCW);

                canvas.clipPath(path);
  Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;
  canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 
                                new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
    sourceBitmap.getHeight()), 
                                new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
    targetHeight), null);
  return targetBitmap;
 }
```

For providing border around your imageView :

Add this xml inside your drawable folder :

=>rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Hope , this will helps

Comment: This is not exact round :(  its a rounded rectangle i am getting

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This
    public static Bitmap createRoundImage(Bitmap loadedImage) {
    System.out.println("loadbitmap" + loadedImage);
    loadedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, 100, 100, true);
    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage.getWidth(),
            loadedImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(loadedImage,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    c.drawCircle(loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, loadedImage.getHeight() / 2,
            loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    return circleBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: circular image view with rounded white border]

By using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android) i have successfully made it, using a `FrameLayout` and **two** `RoundedImageView`. The logic behind what i did is one is a wrapper view and one is the view with the profile image. Here is my code

**XML code:**

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/llImageProfile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">


    <com.pepperpk.frt.mallpk.custom.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleViewOverlay"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <com.pepperpk.frt.mallpk.custom.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**JAVA code :**

```
profileWrapper.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_background);
profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
```

hope it helps, if you have any confusion please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried keeping ImageView inside CardView and adjusted radius of the CardView accordingly.

NetworkImageView is the one from Volley Library.
Same Should work with ImageView as well.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_image_view"
            app:cardCornerRadius="53dp"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:background="@color/reco_widget_search_background"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="1">

            <NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/circle_networkImageViewProduct"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -12):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img {
border: 30px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 130px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
background: #000;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>try</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/1024/google-icon.png" width="48" height="48" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We are talking android here sir, this is some html code that could be used in a webView but ...

Comment: This is CSS, not Android

Comment: Not related to android, this is CSS