# Shape as background, border so small

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-layout

I tried to add a thin border around my rounded imageView.
To do this, i decided to add a shape as background with a padding.
The result is good, there is a thin border around my imageview but this border is so small. I would like to have a border around 3dp.

I tried to play with different size (padding, corner) but the result is not good.
Perhaps, there is a problem in my xml :

shape_rounded.xml :

```
<stroke android:width="5dp"
    android:color="#000000"
    />

<padding android:left="3dp"
    android:top="3dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:bottom="3dp"
    />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
```

And here is how i use it :

```html
<com.frisbeeeapp.frisbeee.utilities.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_ex"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rounded"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cover2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: what about put your ImageView into LinearLayout and put the padding=1  in the LinearLayout, you'll have a 1px  border. hope this help :) ...

Comment: It will not work because i use rounded imageview no ?

Comment: Change the size of the stroke attribute.

Comment: @MattMatt I tried to change width but there is no effect

Comment: ok !! sorry for that! do you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655264/how-to-add-a-shadow-and-a-border-on-circular-imageview-android

Comment: also this !! https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Comment: Thanks @MaheeraJazi-newaccount- I finally use the CircularImageView class found here : https://github.com/wisemandesigns/CircularImageView Thanks

Comment: Perhaps wrap it a layer-list element?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will help with this:

```
<solid android:color="#00000000" />
<stroke android:width="8dp"
         android:color="#000000"/>
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
```