# How can I change my default ListView to a CardView?

Tags: java, android, listview

As said in the title, how can I change my default `ListView` to a `CardView`? If you don't get what I mean (you probably do get what I mean), a `CardView` is basically Googles new layout `ListView`. It looks like a card and looks simple and neat. I'm just wondering how I can change my `ListView` to that.

Comment: There is no `CardView` among views at `Android SDK`, you are refencing 3rd party libs

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of examples on SO how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731268/android-card-view-has-thin-gray-line-in-between-cards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571118/how-to-create-google-cards-ui-in-a-list-view