# Android list items with card styles and same options like Google Play Music

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-styles

I want to make my list view have styles like cards on most of apps Google uses like Google play music, or notes or even in Google now cards, I will show you what i mean in pics:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv9S0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzaLf.png

Also I want every item have same options like adding to cart and so on, and is it possible to get list of items from an online server in xml format?

I will appreciate if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways:

- Via [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571277/2219600) background.
- Via 9-patch [image](http://www.tiemenschut.com/simply-get-cards-ui-look/) background for your list cell.

Some of the third party libs are:

- [Cardslib](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib) by gabrielemariotti.
- [Staggered gridview](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) with cards layout.

Here is a psd design for cards UI:

- [Flat UI](https://dribbble.com/shots/1377595-Flat-UI-kit-psd?list=searches&tag=free&offset=406) Cards by Hugo

Comment: Thank you your links will help, what about getting items from a server? I need to update my list items from a xml file from an online server. Could you please help in this one too?

Comment: Here is a detailed tutorial of xml parsing http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/